# Multiple THEN to a single CASE statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to add an extra column. This extra column will get a value based on a case statment. My objective is for instance, although the syntax is very wrong, something to accomplish this: When 'A' then 'Apple' AND 'ExtraColumn'=1. I have tried to create an equvialnt to this using the code below, but I get an error that my SQL syntax is incorrect.

```
select Patient,
case ColumnName 
when 'A' then 'Apple'  
when 'B' then 'Banana'
end ColumnName, 
case ExtraColumn 
when 'A' then '1'  
when 'B' then '2'
end ExtraColumn, 

ColumnResult
from TABLE

unpivot
(
ColumnResult

for ColumnName in (COL1,COL2,COL3)

for ExtraColumn in (COL1,COL2,COL3)

)u
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to repeat your case construct for each column name.  Something like this:

```
case ColumnName 
when 'A' then 'Apple'  
when 'B' then 'Banana'
end ColumnName, 

case ColumnName
when 'A' then '1'  
when 'B' then '2'
end ExtraColumn,
```

There is a gotcha here.  If you use ColumnName in your where clause, you might not like the results because you used it as an alias.

**Edit starts here**

You can make your aliases whatever you want.  If they are simple, just type them.

```
 select column1 fred, column2 barney
```

If you want more than one word, or an sql keyword, use double quotes

```
select column1 "fred flinstone", column2 "select"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The concept worked, but now I have 2 columns, one called 'ColumnName' and the second is 'ColumnName_1'. Is there anyway to change the 'ColumnName_1' to read something I specify?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `decode`

```
select decode(ColumnName ,'A', 'Apple','B','Banana', 'Unknown') from ....
```