# Is there a way to do multiple things in a CASE statement THEN section using MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and `MYSQL` and am trying to set a value in a `UPDATE` statement using a `CASE` statement. I am trying to do two things in the `THEN`  section of the `CASE` statement and cannot figure out if it's a syntax problem or not possible to do two things in the `THEN` section.

I have looked up these two question and have not been able to connect these two questions to what I am trying to do:

[Multiple THEN to a single CASE statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309443/multiple-then-to-a-single-case-statement)

[update mysql with if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001217/update-mysql-with-if-condition)

My Current Attempt

```
UPDATE offering, tmpTable
SET offering.offNumEnrolled = CASE WHEN offering.OffNumEnrolled = 0 
                              THEN (tmpTable.stdTotal SET aRowsAltered = aRowsAltered + 1) 
                              ELSE (offering.offNumEnrolled) END
WHERE [some condition]
```

To better illustrate what I am trying to accomplish here is this code:

```
UPDATE offering, tmpTable
SET offering.offNumEnrolled = IF (offering.OffNumEnrolled = 0) THEN
                                    (SET TO THIS tmpTable.stdTotal AND 
                                    SET aRowsAltered = aRowsAltered + 1)
                                 ELSE
                                    SET offering.offNumEnrolled;
                                 END IF;
WHERE [some condition]
```

What would be the proper way of setting the value and incrementing a counter if the row was changed?

Comment: why do you want rowsaltered  if it cant get via `sql%rowcount`, just update  the table!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
UPDATE offering o JOIN
       tmpTable tt
       ON  <join conditions here>
    SET o.offNumEnrolled = tt.stdTotal, 
        ?.aRowsAltered = ?.aRowsAltered + 1
    WHERE o.OffNumEnrolled = 0;
```

The `?` is the table alias for wherever `aRowsAltered` comes from.  It is probably optional in this case, but a good practice in general to qualify column names.

Notes:

- MySQL supports `JOIN` in the `UPDATE` clause.  Use it.
- The `JOIN` conditions should go in an `ON` clause.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You only want to update certain rows, so the condition on `o.OffNumEnrolled = 0` goes in the `WHERE` clause.
- MySQL allows you to update multiple tables at once, so `aRowsAltered` can be modified regardless of which table it is in .